# Is there an API or website where I can see all addresses that hold a specific native token/asset?

Tags: native-assets, api

I want to get all addresses that hold a specific native asset/token. I'm not talking about NFTs but tokens that have a quantity of more than one. Examples would be the [spacecoins](https://pool.pm/d894897411707efa755a76deb66d26dfd50593f2e70863e1661e98a0.spacecoins) or the [hosks](https://pool.pm/98dc68b04026544619a251bc01aad2075d28433524ac36cbc75599a1.hosk).

I want to do this using an API or a website (without running my own full node). Options would be [blockfrost.io](https://blockfrost.io) or other websites like [pool.pm](https://pool.pm), [cardanoscan.io](https://cardanoscan.io), [explorer.cardano.org](https://explorer.cardano.org/) or similar services.

Are there tools that can do this already out there somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [Blockfrost.io's `/assets/{asset}/addresses`](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Assets/paths/%7E1assets%7E1%7Basset%7D%7E1addresses/get) endpoint that lists all addresses containing a specific asset.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. If there are other services that provide the same functionality, I'd still be interested to know about them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a website called [cardanoassets.com](https://cardanoassets.com) where one can see the mint history and transactions that include a specific asset. This doesn't answer the question but is related so I'm leaving it here too.

Example: https://cardanoassets.com/spacecoins-250